# Error while creating new subsite in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sub-site

On our production site, While creating new subsite using any template, We are getting below error,

> One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields.

I'm looking for the root cause, I found some default SharePoint site columns & content types are missing. Those could be accidentally deleted OR may be corrupted. My question is, can we restore those defaults , If yes then how?

Comment: is the issue happening on every site or just one?

Comment: on root site as well as on all subsites.

Comment: Did you check if the "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" is activated ? If yes, try de-activating and then activating again, if no try to activate it. @SPDeveloper

Comment: @sohail There are more than 200 subsites under site collection & this is production environment.

Comment: @SPDeveloper You could just check for 3-4 sites and if it is deactivated, then use powershell to activate the feature for those sites and check if the site columns and content types are retained.

Comment: SharePoint will not allow me to deactivate "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" at site collection unless I deactivate "SharePoint Server Publishing Feature" from all subsites first.

Comment: To restore default content types on SharePoint in situ we use this stsadm -o deactivatefeature -name Fields -url http://sitecoll -force
stsadm -o activatefeature -name Fields -url http://sitecoll -force try to find equivalent in SharePoint Online